# scripts.ini no such file or directory

Tags: tex4ht, scripts

I have a problem with usage of tex4th package.
I installed it, however when I want to check if it works I receive the following error:

**ht: No such file or directory: C:\Program Files (x86)...\MiKTeX\miktex\config\scripts.ini
ht: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)...\MiKTeX\miktex\config\scripts.ini**

Where I can get scripts.ini, and what it should contain.

Could anyone help me?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: could you try to run `htlatex` instead of `ht`?

Comment: When I use htlatex I have the same error.
Maybe package is installed in a wrong way. I really don't know.(((

Comment: scripts.ini is a core miktex file. If it isn't there something is really wrong. How did you install miktex? Did you something special to install tex4ht?

Comment: Out Miktex works well. Scripts.ini file is absent for a several years, as far as I remember my work with Miktex on our company. Miktex  is installed in a simple way, automatically. i don't know any details.

Comment: Is your miktex installed in `C:\Program Files\...`   or in ``C:\Program Files  (x86)\...``?